# Manipulate browser history in Cypress

Tags: javascript, react-native, browser, cypress

I'm using [Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress) for integration testing. On the page I have added "Back" button. I want to test, that when I click that button, the browser displays the previous page. I'm looking for a way to add some url in browser history from Cypress. This way, I'll click the button, I'll check that corresponding page is rendered and that's all. Is there any way from Cypress to manipulate browser history? For example like:

```
cy.history.push(newUrl);
```

or something?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like we can use native JS API to add URL in the history.
Here is the reference of similar [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/128) and how to use [*pushState*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

```js
cy.window().then((win) => {
  win.history.pushState(...)
})

// or 

cy.window().its('history').invoke('pushState', ...)
```